# error: cant't find command linux when booting system

Tags: linux, debian, centos, boot, grub

Recently I've installed CentOS 7 on my pc, previously I had debian 7 and manjaro installed. When I installed manjaro I overwrote the bootloader of debian and manjaro's grub recognized the two systems and all worked perfectly, now that I installed CentOS I overwrote /boot/efi and the new grub recognized the three systems but only CentOS works. When I try to boot debian or manjaro the following message appears:

```
error: cant't find command linux
error: cant't find command initrd
```

Comment: CentOS probably cleared the MBR with its own. May need to fix off a live cd

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled? In that case, CentOS GRUB might be restricted to using only the `linuxefi` and `initrdefi` keywords instead of plain `linux` and `initrd`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is  the `linux` and `initrd` command used in `/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` is not found in your centos (or any default boot OS).

You must replace the `linux` to `linuxefi` and `initrd` to `initrdefi` inside the **grub.cfg** file.So follow this operatins:

1 - boot to your centos terminal

2 - install grub2-efi

```
# yum install grub2-efi
```

4 - open the `/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` using a text editor.

```
# vi /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

**note:** if grub.cfg did not exist try to `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`... if was not exist too, try to generate that: `# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg`

5 - find all `linux` command and replace to linuxefi. So, find all initrd command and replace to initrdefi

befor edit saples

> **linux** /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-d1268bb1d6df49758a1ec5715984725c
>   root=/dev/sda1
>   **initrd**
>   /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-d1268bb1d6df49758a1ec5715984725c.img

after edit sample :

> **linuxefi** /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-d1268bb1d6df49758a1ec5715984725c
>   root=/dev/sda1
>   **initrdefi**
>   /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-d1268bb1d6df49758a1ec5715984725c.img

6 - reboot

Comment: I have been struggling for hours with an EFI system that wouldn't boot, and this finally made the difference.  (Why isn't it documented anywhere?) Thank you.