# move boot partition of proxmox (or debian) to USB flash, installed on two NVME disks in zfs-raid-1 on a non-bootable legacy bios

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader, proxmox

I am trying to setup proxmox on Dell r720xd, which does have UEFI boot option but can not boot from PCIe nvme drives.

If I install proxmox (or any os) on a usb flash, it boots fine.

For testing, I installed CentOS with advanced partitioning, and used USB flash as `/boot` partition, and nvme for all other partitions and that too works flawlessly.

With proxmox, there is no custom partitioning option during the setup, so I was unable to set usb key as `/boot` partition during install.

Other option listed in proxmox forums are

- use clover as bootloader on a USB key, described [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/bootable-nvme-install-on-old-hardware-made-easy-with-pcie-adapter-and-clover.78120/)
- install debian first with custom partition and then install proxmox over it and remove debian kernel.

Obviously clover is adding a boot partition on usb and then forwarding the control to nvme.

My question is, how to install proxmox on nvme and then migrate the `/boot` partition to the usb flash?

Seems like a very straight forward process and I followed [this guide](https://www.win-raid.com/t4633f50-Guide-How-to-boot-linux-from-NVME-with-legacy-bios.html) to handle it, however, I could not get it to work. grub2 always complained with messages like

- not matching UUID
- you need to load kernel first
- and so on

any hints please.
P.S. I also tried to edit the centos `/boot` installed on flash drive, by using `grub2-mkconfig` which found the proxmox and updated the `grub.cfg` but still got errors during boot like

- error: cant't find command linux
- error: cant't find command initrd
  fixed these errors ([ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195583/error-cantt-find-command-linux-when-booting-system)) by `linuxefi and initrdefi` but then it could not find the drive with given UUID

Comment: Do not know Clover nor Proxmox. But with grub that error is if grub.cfg does not have correct UUID or drive like (hd0,1) in its settings. When I boot from USB, my system changes drive order. My flash drive becomes hd0, and every other drive moves up one. And my internal NVMe when installed was not hd0 but hd1 and with flash drive becomes hd2. I use grub to loopmount, but often have to manually edit a working grub stanza with different hdX if flash drive also plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is very simple to achieve. the only problem is it is kind of confusingly documented.

here are the steps that you need to perform

1. install proxmox (using DEBUG mode) on your nvme drive (which may not
   be bootable due to legacy BIOS)
2. once the install is complete, do not exit the install wizard, but start the command terminal. (Selecting debug mode in first step will
   make it easy to open the terminal)
3. chroot (check link in the question, i think it is optional)
4. run `proxmox-boot-tool format /dev/sda2` where /dev/sda2 is your usb drive that you want to use as boot drive.
5. run `proxmox-boot-tool init /dev/sda2` and wait for the setup to complete.

in my system I used chroot step and it works flawlessly, but you may or may not need the chroot step

ref: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Host_Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

This answer started as a comment on @nexlin's original answer but it kind of outgrew the comment size and features (links) so I made it an answer instead.

Noting that the author of the original Q&A is the same person, AND the answer was posted ~1 month after the question. Kudos to the author for coming back to share their solution, which was insightful for their specific situation... needing/finding a solution during the proxmox installation. It is valuable to share that changing the boot drive can be done during the proxmox installation steps, and that the proxmox installer in debug mode offers this facility.

---

I think its helpful to share that moving the proxmox boot drive can also be resolved after the installation regardless of whether the proxmox install can boot or not, by booting from the proxmox installer in console mode and entering the root shell by using the shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, and running the required steps with `proxmox-boot-tool` to configure a bootable drive.

I had a similar scenario with a legacy (v4) proxmox installation.

I was inspired by:

1. @nexlin's answer to this question
2. Proxmox forum user **whytf**. Who posted their solution for using USB to boot a proxmox installation [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/move-boot-partition-zfs-usb.137870/#post-617982).

Which inspired me to write up my guide entitled: [Proxmox: Switching from legacy boot when there is no space for ESP partition](https://coda.io/@ff0/home-lab-data-vault/proxmox-switching-from-legacy-boot-when-there-is-no-space-for-es-21).

My aim with this answer is to provide more background info and some other *more general* solutions (see the links) to answer the original question. I hope it helps someone in the future.

While it would be possible to copy/paste re-host the solutions in this answer, I feel that this would take them out of context or reduce fidelity, so I have chosen not to re-host the content here. This answer should be a comment, but it doesn't fit.